# Two partial views.Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render two partial views. One has a form and other one has a list. When an item is added using the form, the list should update.

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    // GET: MetalStock
    public PartialViewResult AddMetalStock()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
public ViewResult AddMetalStock(MetalStockViewModel                metalStockViewModel) 
    {
        var metalDto = new MetalStockDto();
        metalDto.GlobalMaterialId = Guid.NewGuid();
        metalDto.Category = "Metal";
        this.metalStockRepository.Insert(metalDto);
        this.metalStockRepository.SaveChanges();
        return View("Index");

    }

    public PartialViewResult AllMetalStockItems()
    {
        var allMetalDtos = this.metalStockRepository.GetAllMetalSotckDtos();

        var allMetalViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MetalStockDto>,IEnumerable<MetalStockViewModel>>(allMetalDtos);
        return PartialView("_AllMetalStockItems", allMetalViewModels );
    }
```

View :Index

```
<h2>Metal Stock</h2>
@Html.Action("AllMetalStockItems","MetalStock")

@Html.Action("AddMetalStock","MetalStock")
```

Now when I add an item I get the following error

> Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.

What's the cause behind this? How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's some recursive loop here but can't figure it out at the moment where it is.

Comment: You need to show your partial view for `AddMetalStock` and `_AllMetalStockItems`. Also try commenting out one of the `@Html.Action()` methods, then the other to narrow down which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try change

```
<h2>Metal Stock</h2>
@Html.Action("AllMetalStockItems","MetalStock")

@Html.Action("AddMetalStock","MetalStock")
```

To

```
<h2>Metal Stock</h2>
@Url.Action("AllMetalStockItems","MetalStock")

@Url.Action("AddMetalStock","MetalStock")
```

Because the page was recursively calling itself.

Comment: It produces this

Metal Stock
/MetalStock/AllMetalStockItems /MetalStock/AddMetalStock

It doesn't load the partial views for some reason